# Create-react-app rendering SVG but not PNG

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm adding background images by css.

When I'm adding SVG images it`s working fine.

```
background: url(./logo.svg)
```

But when I'm adding PNG images it`s not working.

```
background: url(./logo.png)
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you try this : 

import image from './sun.png';

var styles = {
color:'violet',
backgroundImage: 'url('+image+')'
};

Comment: And you're sure logo.png exists in the correct directory?

Comment: @udayakumar Thanks a lot for your reply. But it didn't work.

Comment: @DanielApt Yes. It was in the right path.

Comment: I got the same issue, run in develop mode `npm start` is ok, but when run the build comment, only copy *.svg files and ignore *.png files